# Touch ID screen appears twice

Tags: ios, authentication, local, touch-id

I have implement a lock screen, where after every 3 idle minutes i launch a pass word screen. If the user has touch ID, then i launch the Touch ID.

```
 OCTouchIdManager *touchManager = [[OCTouchIdManager alloc]init];


 if([touchManager isTouchIdAvilable] &&(userEabled) && passphraseLockStatusValue ){
        [touchManager authenticateUserSuccess:^(void){

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self proceedOnSuccess];
                });

            });



        }
                                fallBackBlock:^(NSInteger error){

                                    //if error 1 then fall back (either the user clicked cancel or enter password)
                                    //if error 2 then touch id fail (wrong finger)

                                    if(error==1){
                                        // do nothing, assume that the user will now user the mass passphase lock to verify.
                                    }else if (error ==2){
                                        [self showInvalidPasswordAlert];
                                    }

                                }];
    }
```

and my touchIDManager

```
-(void)authenticateUserSuccess:(TouchIdSuccessBlock)successBlock fallBackBlock:(TouchIdFallBackBlock)fallbackBlock{
    self.laContext.localizedFallbackTitle=@"Enter Passphrase";
    [self.laContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                   localizedReason:@"Please Login With your Touch ID to continue."
                             reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

                                 if (error) {
                                     //There was a problem verifying your identity"
                                     fallbackBlock(1);
                                     return;
                                 }
                                 if (success) {
                                     successBlock();

                                 } else {
                                     //"You are not the device owner."

                                     fallbackBlock(2);
                                 }
                             }];
}
```

However some times in some devices the touch ID screen appears Twice. meaning, there is a small flicker.
The issue is very minor, but still it annoys many users. does any one else have issue ? how do I solve it.

Comment: Did you copy the code? Because you have a typo: `if([touchManager isTouchIdAvilable]` "Available". Maybe that's wrong throughout the code. Anyways, do you mean the "Please Log In..." shows up twice? Before touching, or it shows up again after touching?

Comment: thats a typo. its my own method so no problem with that.
Everything work fine. 
Yeah I'm talking about the Pleas login.. screen. It even works fine on my simulator. But on real device there is small flicker. the screen appears twice.

Comment: I don't know if it's similar or not, but I had a problem with detecting a scrollViewDidScroll, where it called it multiple times because it was still scrolling. My solution was to insert a boolean at the beginning of the function, that prevented it from being called twice. Then I reset the bool at the end of the function.

Comment: my evaluatePolicy is getting called only ones. confirm. I even have break point. but still there is a small flicker.

Comment: I got the same problem and I didn't figure out why